# Collision between two rectangles - libGDX

Tags: android, libgdx, rotation, collision-detection

I'm making a game in which the objective is to collect the maximum amount of balls(Rectangle) to get the highest score. The balls spawn randomly from the middle of every side of your smartphone, and you use the square in the middle of your screen (**the square rotates 90 degrees to the right every time the screen is touched**) to get the balls. The square(Rectangle) has three black sides and one yellow side.

What I'm trying to accomplish here is to make so that if a ball hits the yellow side of the square you get one point but if a ball hits the black side of the square, you lose the game.

Here's what I have so far (**Already have the collisions, rotation and the balls spawning**):

```
@Override
public void create(){

    batch = new SpriteBatch();

    Ball = new Texture("energyball.png");
    Up = new Texture("up.png");

    upSprite = new Sprite(Up);

    upSprite.setOriginCenter();
    upSprite.setX(615);
    upSprite.setY(340);
    upSprite.setRegionWidth(64);
    upSprite.setRegionHeight(64);

    square = new Rectangle();

    square.set(630, 360, 32, 32);

    cam = new OrthographicCamera();
    cam.setToOrtho(false, 1280, 720);

    upSprite.setPosition(upSprite.getX(), upSprite.getY());

    // calls the functions to spawn balls randomly
    balls1 = new Array<Rectangle>();
    spawnBalls1();

    balls2 = new Array<Rectangle>();
    spawnBalls2();

    balls3 = new Array<Rectangle>();
    spawnBalls3();

    balls4 = new Array<Rectangle>();
    spawnBalls4();

    score();


    //if the screen is touched sprite rotates 90 degrees clockwise
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(new InputAdapter() {

        @Override
        public boolean touchDown(int x, int y, int pointer, int button) {

            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean touchUp(int x, int y, int pointer, int button) {

            upSprite.rotate(-90);
            return true;
        }
    });


}


//shows score
private void score() {

    score = 0;
    showScore = "Score: 0";
    scoreFont = new BitmapFont();

}


//creates the balls and sets their position as well as the random timer for each
private void spawnBalls1() {

    ball1.x = MathUtils.random(639, 641);
    ball1.y = 720;
    ball1.width = 32;
    ball1.height = 32;
    balls1.add(ball1);
    lastDropTime = TimeUtils.nanoTime();

}

private void spawnBalls2() {

    ball2.x = 0;
    ball2.y = MathUtils.random(359, 361);
    ball2.width = 32;
    ball2.height = 32;
    balls2.add(ball2);
    lastDropTime = TimeUtils.nanoTime();
}

private void spawnBalls3() {

    ball3.x = MathUtils.random(639, 641);
    ball3.y = 0;
    ball3.width = 32;
    ball3.height = 32;
    balls3.add(ball3);
    lastDropTime = TimeUtils.nanoTime();
}

private void spawnBalls4() {

    ball4.x = 1280;
    ball4.y = MathUtils.random(359, 361);
    ball4.width = 32;
    ball4.height = 32;
    balls4.add(ball4);
    lastDropTime = TimeUtils.nanoTime();
}

@Override
public void render() {

    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    cam.update();

    //draws the game itself as well as the balls on the screen
    batch.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);
    batch.begin();

    upSprite.draw(batch);

    //draws the balls
    for (Rectangle ball1 : balls1) {

        batch.draw(Ball, ball1.x, ball1.y);
    }

    for (Rectangle ball2 : balls2) {

        batch.draw(Ball, ball2.x, ball2.y);
    }

    for (Rectangle ball3 : balls3) {

        batch.draw(Ball, ball3.x, ball3.y);
    }

    for (Rectangle ball4 : balls4) {

        batch.draw(Ball, ball4.x, ball4.y);
    }

    scoreFont.setColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
    scoreFont.draw(batch, showScore, 25, 100);

    batch.end();

    // if the time minus the time of the last ball spawn is less than x then spawn another ball in a random place

    if (TimeUtils.nanoTime() - lastDropTime > 1000000000) {

        switch (MathUtils.random(4)) {

            case 0:
                spawnBalls1();
                break;

            case 1:
                spawnBalls2();
                break;

            case 2:
                spawnBalls3();
                break;

            case 3:
                spawnBalls4();
                break;
        }
    }

    Iterator<Rectangle> iter1 = balls1.iterator();
    while(iter1.hasNext()) {

        Rectangle balls1 = iter1.next();
        balls1.y -= 350 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
        if (balls1.overlaps(square)) {

            score++;
            showScore = "Score: " + score;
            iter1.remove();
        }

    }

    Iterator<Rectangle> iter2 = balls2.iterator();
    while (iter2.hasNext()) {

        Rectangle balls2 = iter2.next();
        balls2.x += 550 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
        if (balls2.overlaps(square)) {
            score++;
            showScore = "Score: " + score;
            iter2.remove();
        }

    }


    Iterator<Rectangle> iter3 = balls3.iterator();
    while(iter3.hasNext()) {

        Rectangle balls3 = iter3.next();
        balls3.y += 350 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
        if (balls3.overlaps(square)) {

            score++;
            showScore = "Score: " + score;
            iter3.remove();
        }
    }

    Iterator<Rectangle> iter4 = balls4.iterator();
    while(iter4.hasNext()) {

        Rectangle balls4 = iter4.next();
        balls4.x -= 550 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
        if (balls4.overlaps(square)) {

            score++;
            showScore = "Score: " + score;
            iter4.remove();
        }

    }

}
```

Will be really glad if anyone could help me out. Thanks!!

Comment: Besides removing duplicate code and shrinking the code above I recommend using one line/rectangle for each site which forms the "real" rectangle. Then do collision detection against each site.

Comment: Should I use shapeRenderer?

Comment: You can, but most of the time its easier to separate "model" (rectangles, lines, collision) with "view" (something drawn on the screen).

Comment: I'm not sure how I can do so unfortunately, can you try to give me an example please?

Answer (score 0):

I can not write properly code right now but you can use this logic,

1. create line object on yellow to catch collision
2. whenever you turn square, change this line's position too

I hope, i understand your need and could be helpful.

Comment: Yeah I get that idea, I don't know how to execute it unfortunately. Am I supposed to use shapeRenderer?

Sorry for the late response

Comment: Actually i didn't use this [objects and methods](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/math/Intersector.html) but I think you can find same usage on internet,

Comment: You think you can make me an example? I've never used it and I'm not understanding how. or is it too much to ask. I'm really in need of it

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't make you an example but I hope you can make a solution with this method.

[Intersector](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/math/Intersector.java)

```
public static boolean intersectRaySphere (Ray ray, Vector3 center, float radius, Vector3 intersection) {
    final float len = ray.direction.dot(center.x - ray.origin.x, center.y - ray.origin.y, center.z - ray.origin.z);
    if (len < 0.f) // behind the ray
        return false;
    final float dst2 = center.dst2(ray.origin.x + ray.direction.x * len, ray.origin.y + ray.direction.y * len,
        ray.origin.z + ray.direction.z * len);
    final float r2 = radius * radius;
    if (dst2 > r2)
        return false;
    if (intersection != null)
        intersection.set(ray.direction).scl(len - (float)Math.sqrt(r2 - dst2)).add(ray.origin);
    return true;
}
```